# laravel view component class not send data to view component in live server

Tags: laravel, view, components

> Undefined variable: datanews (View:
> `/home1/ctgroirh/public_html/maqsudan.ctgroup.in/maqsudan/resources/views/components/news.blade.php)`

http://maqsudan.ctgroup.in/open

**Working fine in local machine but not working in live server.**

check below code I pass data to view.

```
  return view('components.news',["datanews"=>$datanews ]);
```

below is local machine screen shot , which is working fine.

[image]

**News blade code:**

```
<div>
    <!-- Act only according to that maxim whereby you can, at the same time, will that it should become a universal law. - Immanuel Kant -->

 <h2 class="bggridient" style="color:white;padding:10px;text-align:center;">
   News    </h2>
 <?php 
  for ($x = 0; $x < count($datanews); $x++) {
     
    ?>
 data come here
   
    <?php 
  }
    
    ?>

<center> <a href="/All-News" class="btn btn-default"> More News</a> </center>




</div>
```

**View Component class**

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;
use App\Models\campusevent;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class news extends Component
{
    public $data;
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {  
        $datanews=campusevent::where('Type',"=" ,'1')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(4)->get();

        return view('components.news',["datanews"=>$datanews ]);
    }
}
```

**DD Use**

```
dd($datanews->toArray());
```

[image]

**Database table and data exist**

[image]

Comment: post blade code  to question.also controller method full code

Comment: also try to clear cache .php artisan view:clear ,php artisan clear

Comment: i add both component view and its class

Comment: I pass data to view component from its class

Comment: everything is working fine in local machine , but i transfer files to sever it show undefined variable error

Comment: clear cache once in server .by running command.php artisan view:clear  and php artisan cache:clear

Comment: shared hosting , no terminal available for any command, php artisan view:clear   . i am working in local machine and just uploading files to server

Comment: delete cache viewed file from \storage\framework\views

Comment: http://maqsudan.ctgroup.in/open   , not working ,

Comment: I delete all files from \storage\framework\views  even problem is same

Comment: i change version from php 7.4 to 7.3 , also not working

Comment: try dd($datanews->toArray()); before returning view

Comment: it is display data in screen in  local machine but no effect in maqsudan.ctgroup.in/open.

Comment: fist check you have data in database tables etc....

Comment: I check , data available , attachment photo attached above

Comment: hello this is not working boss ?

Comment: not sure what exactly is causing.let some other might help you

Comment: i think view component class not working that why dd not work in server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename component class name , so that it must start with uppercase letter.

```
class News extends Component{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**lowercase class name working in development but not work in production. this error or bug may be from the Laravel framework.**

Just change the name of the component class from  lowercase to Uppercase

**first letter must be capital**

like below ->

```
class news extends Component{
              }
```

to

```
class News extends Component {
        }
```

And rename component from `<x-news /> to <x-News />`

and its working

Answer (score 1):

yes! this works!!! the problem was **"first letter must be capital"**

I don't know why, but in server Laravel recognize the component like an "Anonymous Component", so in view we don't have anyting of the class.

In my case, I have this name:
`class ComponentOne extends Component`

and to use:

```
<x-Component-one :param1="$miParam" :param2="otherParam"/>
```